# Fade elements as they reach the top of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrolltop

So I'm using jQuery script like so;

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".element").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 700);
  });
```

to hide an absolutely positioned, flexbox element as it is scrolled out of the top of the page. I have other content further down on the page that I would like to apply this same set of rules on; I would like them to be at 100% opacity when they're visible towards the bottom of the page and then have them fade out as the user scrolls, but this only seems to work on the first element that's shown in the window initially. I'm not sure why this is - I've played around with the `700` value but it never seems accurate for the elements further down the page.

[Here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6oadup55/)

The content that I'm doing with this is both text and images. I'm thinking that this might not be possible in the way I had hoped - IF I can get this to work, ideally a text block is faded out from the top to the bottom instead of the entire element at once, but I understand that with this method that is probably not possible.

Comment: Instead of dividing / 700, you can divide by the offset of the element, like this: $(".textblock").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / $(".textblock").offset().top);

Comment: That is because the scrollTop is only based on the viewport itself, while your elements are in various part of the code. You will have to iterate through each element, and check its relative position from the top of the viewport, and then decide to fade it or not (or the extent of fading).

Comment: something like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/6oadup55/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest that you use a common class for all the elements for which the fading behavior is intended. You may also use a combination of selectors. The main issue with your implementation is that you can only listening to the viewport's scroll position, ignoring the fact that different elements on the page have different vertical distances from the top of the document. **You will have to compute the position of the element relative to the top of the viewport instead**.

Therefore, to do this, you will have to:

1. Iterate through each element that you want to fade when scrolling
2. Calculate its vertical offset relative to the top of the viewport (which is basically the element's top offset position minus the current scroll position)
3. If this offset crosses a certain threshold (can be a pixel value, or a percentage of the viewport height), start computing the fade

In my proof-of-concept example below, I have:

- Applied a common class to all items that are to be faded
- Added rudimentary settings, so that the fade out starts only when the element is more than halfway up the viewport (the top half of the viewport can be seen as the "fade zone")
- Linear interpolation between the opacity value and the position of the element within the "fade zone"

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  // Setting: Start fading halfway up the page
  var startPos = 0.5;

  // Cache window object
  var $w = $(window);

  // Basically, we go through each element and check its relative position within the viewport
  $('.scrollFade').each(function() {

    // Get current relative position in viewport, based on the top edge
    var pos = $(this).offset().top - $w.scrollTop();

    // Get viewport height
    var vh = $w.height();

    if (pos < vh * startPos) {
      // If element has past the starting threshold, we fade it
      $(this).css('opacity', pos / (vh * startPos) * 1);
    } else {
      $(this).css('opacity', 1);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.textblock {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.extratext {
  margin-top: 500px;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="textblock scrollFade">
    hey hey hey!
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p class="extratext scrollFade">
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: this is a really great solution. i hadn't even thought of calculating the value from the top. very well done, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```
.topGradient{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background:linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index: 100;
}


.bottomGradient{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
background:linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));   position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/z4rhb378/)

What I did was create 2 div and place them at the top and bottom of the window. Then I set them above all other elements using z-index and then gave them a gradient back having transparency, thus giving you the fade-in/out effect of the elements as you mentioned.

Comment: i really like this solution and i actually tried to implement something just like this but i have a full screen video with fixed positioning in the background of this website so i'd rather not have the gradient showing on top of the elements that aren't text. if there's a way to manipulate z-index's or psuedo elements to make this possible it would be perfect, but i don't think there is

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the elements position on the page and use it as an offset to when the fade starts. [Here is an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6oadup55/3/).

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".textblock").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 700);
    var offsetTop = $(".extratext").offset().top;
    $(".extratext").css("opacity", 1 - ($(window).scrollTop() - offsetTop) / 700);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fadeAtTop(el) {
    const startPos = 0.25;
    const $window = $(window);
    const viewportHeight = $window.height();

    el.toArray().forEach(el => {
      const $el = $(el);
      let position = $el.offset().top - $window.scrollTop();
      let opacity = position < viewportHeight * startPos ? position / (viewportHeight * startPos) * 1 : 1;

      $el.css('opacity', opacity);
    });
  }
```